# How do I do a raw write to a cd with dd?

Tags: clipboard, iso, dd, cd-image

How do I do a raw write to my CD drive `/dev/scd0`? I want to write a bootloader (that takes two sectors) directly onto a CD, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

As CDs are not traditional block devices, writing via dd will likely not result in a usable CD.  If you want to write an image to a CD, use the `wodim` tool (what used to be known as `cdrecord`).

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrom file.iso
```

Alternatively, you can use the graphical `Brasero Disc Burner` application included in the default install of Ubuntu.

Note also that a different process is used to boot off a CD compared to booting off a block device like a hard disk.  Rather than just executing code found in the first sectors of the image, it makes use of a process called the [El Torito Bootable CD Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29).  In effect there is a table in the CD image that says where to find boot loaders for one or more CPU architectures.  The boot loader either exists directly on the CD itself, or inside a floppy disk image.  In the latter case, the BIOS emulates a floppy drive backed by that image and boots as normal from there.

If you want to boot Linux from the CD, I would suggest using the [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX) boot loader.  A copy of the boot loader can be found in the `syslinux` package.

If you want to use some other custom boot code, the floppy emulation mode might be an easier choice.

Comment: I'm finding it amusing how two different people write almost identical answers within 2 minutes from each other :)

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of shortcomings with your approach...

Firstly, it is generally impossible to write arbitrary sectors on a CD-ROM - unlike the hard drives, optical media does not support random writes. Think about CD-R disks, opening/closing sessions and other stuff.

Secondly, the procedure of booting from a CD is quite different from booting from a HD - in some cases bootable cdroms use an image of a floppy or emulate a harddisk etc. See [El Torito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29) standard for more details

So, to make a bootable CD, I would imagine you need to prepare a bootable ISO image using [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX) or some other boot loader. Burning that ISO to a CDROM using some standard program such as Brasero or K3b would produce a bootable disk.